# MATLAB:How to check if a cell element already exists in a cell array?

Tags: matlab, cell, cell-array

Hello community of stackoverflow,

I have a cell array Q, 5520x1 cell array, which consists of arrays like this for example:

K>> Q{1}

ans =

```
 0     3     1    84
```

and so on.

I'd really like to know, how would it be possible to check if an element of the cell array,like the above, already exists in Q? Because if it does exist, i do not add anything, but if yes, i had to add this element to the end of Q. How could this check be done properly? Short solutions, if possible of course, would be a little more appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your time,
Nick

Comment: By "element" do you mean the whole vector? So for example, with `Q = {[1 2 3], [4 5]}`, the new vector `[2 4]` would go to `Q{3}`?

Comment: @LuisMendo By element i mean the whole vector from which Q consists of, for example Q{1}=[0 3 1 84].  Yes, what i am trying to do is something similiar to a FIFO-style queue, if the check of existence of the "element" is negative, then i have to add the "element" to the end of the queue Q.

Comment: See my answer then for the "check" part. For the "append" part, just use `Q{end+1} = new`. Or, if possible, preallocate

Comment: @LuisMendo I am trying your answer, it must be what i wanted to achieve. Yes, thanks for the  Q{end+1} = new for the "append" part. Give me a few minutes and your answer will be accepted as solution! :-)

Comment: Note that repeatedly using `Q{end+1} = ...` will be slow, due to continual memory reallocation

Comment: Noticed that, thanks once again. Another dumb question of me: Does cellfun slows down the programm? Does it takes extra memory or something?

Comment: `cellfun` is not memory intensive. It's like a `for` loop: traverse the cell array and to each cell `x` apply the function `isequal(x,new)`. As for speed: well, it's more or less a loop, and loops are not the fastest thing in Matlab. But with newest Matlab versions the speed penalty is decreasing. If speed is important, you could transform the `cellfun` into a `for` loop; that may be a little faster

Comment: Ok, gracias Luis for the feedback! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that by "element" you mean the whole vector. So for example, given

```
Q = {[1 2 3], [4 5]}
```

the new vector `[2 4 3]` should be added, but `[4 5]` should not.

To do that check: denoting the new vector by `new`, use

```
alreadyExists = any(cellfun(@(x) isequal(x, new), Q));
```

Examples:

```
>> Q = {[1 2 3], [4 5]};
>> alreadyExists = any(cellfun(@(x) isequal(x, [2 4 3]), Q))
alreadyExists =
     0
>> alreadyExists = any(cellfun(@(x) isequal(x, [4 5]), Q))
alreadyExists =
     1
```